# Is it possible to play multiple sound files sequentially on an onMouseover event?

Tags: javascript, audio, onmouseover

I know how to play a single sound file at a time onMouseover event e.g

```
onMouseover="Playsound(1.wav)
```

However, I want to play **multiple soundfiles** (1.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav etc) **sequentially on a single mouseover** either on an image or other element.

Is it possible at all?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it possible? I don't know. But please don't do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you know lengths of the sounds, you can use setTimeout to play them sequentially

Answer (score 0):

You could do it by attaching a function to the event mouseover i.e.

```
element.addEventListener('mouseover',function () {
    Playsound(1.wav);
    /* do stuff ... if you can retrieve 1.wav length you could use, as semyon mentioned, a setTimeout to play other sounds sequentially i.e. .. */
    setTimeout(playanothersoundfn,GetLength(1.wav));
},false)
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way to do it is to use html5 audio element and register a handler for the ending of the clip:

```
 <audio src="1.wav" id="first"></audio>
 <audio src="2.wav" id="second"></audio>
 audio = document.getElementById('first');
 audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){
   //play next clip
 });
 audio.play();
```

setTimeout is not great for when precise timing is required.  If the first audio clip was a little laggy, your setTimeout will stop on its heels. You are also relying on god knows what is going on at the client.  :-)